# JRadiobutton ActionListener not responding

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm registering the events for two JRadiobuttons, but nothing happens! No errors are thrown, so I'm not being able to trace back the problem..
When selecting the first radio button, it should print out a text. When selecting the second button, it should print out a different text....

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;


public class num2 extends JFrame  {
    private static JLabel type;
    private static JLabel days;
    private static JLabel amt;
    private static JRadioButton checkStandard;
    private static JRadioButton checkExecutive;
    private static JTextField txtDays;
    private static JTextField txtAmount;
    private static JButton btnCalculate;
    private static ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();

    public num2(){
        super("Testing Events");
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        JLabel type = new JLabel("Room Type : ");
        JLabel days = new JLabel("Number Of Days : ");
        JLabel amt = new JLabel("Total Amount : ");

        JRadioButton checkStandard = new JRadioButton("Standard");
        JRadioButton checkExecutive = new JRadioButton("Executive");




        p.setLayout(new FlowLayout());


        group.add(checkStandard);
        group.add(checkExecutive);
        p.add(checkStandard);
        p.add(checkExecutive);
        TheHandler handler = new TheHandler();
        checkStandard.addActionListener(handler);
        checkExecutive.addActionListener(handler);
        add(p);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(100, 100);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        num2 app = new num2();


    }


private class TheHandler implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        Object source = evt.getSource();
        if (source == checkStandard) {
            System.out.println("Done");
         }
        else if(source == checkExecutive){
            System.out.println("nope");
        }

}
}



}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're [shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) both `JRadioButton` variables

```
JRadioButton checkStandard = new JRadioButton("Standard");
JRadioButton checkExecutive = new JRadioButton("Executive");
```

should be

```
checkStandard = new JRadioButton("Standard");
checkExecutive = new JRadioButton("Executive");
```

Comment: +1 for typing faster, but I was also busy typing that you should not be using static variables as this is not necessary.

Comment: was just about to add that as a note...:)